# Select rows where columnA has more than one unique columnB value

Tags: mysql

How can I retrieve rows where `colA` has more than one unique `colB` value?

For example:

```
+------+------+
| colA | colB |
+------+------+
|  1   |  A   |
|  1   |  B   |
|  2   |  C   |
|  3   |  D   |
|  3   |  D   |
+------+------+
```

Given the above data, I'd only like to retrieve the records where `colA = 1`, as that's the only column which has more than one unique value in `colB`.

I can't get my head around it. I have a feeling I'm missing something really obvious.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists` as

```
select * from table_name t1
where exists(
  select 1 from table_name t2
  where t1.colA = t2.colA
  and t1.colB <> t2.colB
)
```

If you are just after finding the colA then you can use

```
select colA from table_name
group by colA
having count(distinct colB) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks - the first query is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ..)` to get the count of distinct column b values for each column a value, and then use a `HAVING` clause to only get what you need:

```
SELECT colA
FROM myTable
GROUP BY colA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT colB) > 1;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50f08/1) example.